# How do you store data in firebase as a json object?

Tags: json, reactjs, firebase

Please hear me out as I know firebase is a json storage. I want to store an actual json string at one of the nodes. the reason being is I need to manually update my app every week with some data. I've json.stringified it online and it returned me a string like so

```
"            { home: 'Everton', away: 'West Brom', result: 'Everton' },\n            { home: 'Leeds', away: 'Fulham', result: 'Leeds' },\n            { home: 'Man United', away: 'Crystal Palace', result: 'Crystal Palace' },\n            { home: 'Arsenal', away: 'West Ham', result: 'Arsenal' },\n            { home: 'Southampton', away: 'Spurs', result: 'Spurs' },\n            { home: 'Newcastle', away: 'Brighton', result: 'Brighton' },\n            { home: 'Chelsea', away: 'Liverpool', result: 'Liverpool' },\n            { home: 'Leicester', away: 'Burnley', result: 'Leicester' },\n            { home: 'Aston Villa', away: 'Sheffield United', result: 'pending' },\n            { home: 'Wolves', away: 'Man City', result: 'pending' },
```

sorry for the awful formatting above but basically it's stringified. the reason I want to do this is that it is much quicker than manually entering them into every node. I quickly update in my text editor then dump into firebase. the problem is though that when I put it in to firebase it's treating it just like a normal string. so I'm not sure then how to turn that into an array on the react fe. any advice on how to do this in firebase?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, and the actual result that doesn't match your expectations.  We should be able to take that code and run it for ourselves to see the result that you're observing.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I will note that both Firebase database products (Realtime Database and Firestore) do not modify strings in any way during reads or writes.  If you are seeing something different, that's probably a result of your code doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is properly stringified, you can use this :

```
var obj = JSON.parse('your string here');
```

Read more about how to use `JSON.parse` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp).

Comment: note: you run that code on your app, not on Firebase

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly legitimate to assign a value to an object property that is a json string. If you do it manually you will need to also manually escape all the double quotes.

JSOn serilaizing methods such as JSON.parse in javascript will do the quote escaping for you

Then when you want to work with that inner json string as a regular object parse the property value back to object.

When the whole main object is stringified for transport, the inner json will have all it's inner quotes escaped

Example:

```js
const obj = {
  someProp: JSON.stringify({foo:'bar'})// json string as value
}
// stringify whole object
const json = JSON.stringify(obj)

console.log('1) Whole object stringified')
//someprop value is escaped json string
console.log(json)

// create new object from full json
const newObj = JSON.parse(json);
// convert the escaped json string value
newObj.someProp = JSON.parse(newObj.someProp)

// access properties as if it was never json
console.log('2) Access property in rebuilt object')
console.log('"newObj.someProp.foo" =',newObj.someProp.foo)
```